# Identify individual networks within dataset containing many (using SAS preferably)

Tags: r, python, sas, networks

I have a dataset of links/edges that looks something like the following (except significantly larger - approx. 50,000 links):

```
Target Source Weight Group
T1     S1     0.50   A
T2     S1     0.50   A
T2     S2     0.25   A
T3     S2     0.75   A
T2     S3     0.35   A
T4     S3     0.65   A
T5     S4     1.00   B
T6     S5     1.00   C
T6     S6     1.00   C
T6     S7     0.80   C
T7     S7     0.20   C
T7     S8     1.00   C
```

The Group identifier in this example doesn't actually exist, but I've placed it here to demonstrate that the observations/links in each of these groups are connected in their own network, and there are no connections across groups A, B and C, etc.

There may be a simple solution but it has evaded me for days. I'm looking for a way to separate this broader dataset into separate datasets that would reflect the groups.

I was hoping to be able to do this in SAS but at this stage I'll take whatever I can - R or Python would be equally suitable.

Thanks in advance!

Aleks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are you looking for [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) in the graph? (They may be easily found e.g. by python [scipy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html))